# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de saber si existe un elemento en el DOM con jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

Pasa que en mi página estoy agregando varios elementos al DOM dinámicamente, utilizando el `.append()` de **jquery**, pero en un div tengo un elemento que quisiera saber antes si existe o no, ya que si le vuelvo a dar un `.append()` el elemento se volvería a agregar repetido.

Se me ocurrió hacer siempre un `.remove()` antes del `.append()` para eliminar cualquier instancia del objeto que haya sido agregada anteriormente. Si me funciona, pero imagino que habrán otras formas mejores de hacerlo?

Comment: Tal vez ".val('');"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si **jQuery** es necesario, puedes usar:

```
if ($('#elemento').length) {
  // si existe
} else {
  // no existe
}
```

Otra solución con **javascript**, tomada de [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains):

```
function isInPage(node) {
  return (node === document.body) ? false : document.body.contains(node);
}
```

Donde node es el elemento que deseas confirmar si existe o no.

Answer (score 4):

Probablemente la forma mas fácil es..

```
if($("#elId").length == 0) {
  //no existe
}
```

o

```
if($(".clase").length == 0) {
  //no hay nada con esa clase
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En un proyecto donde creo un lightbox con vanillajs (sin usar jquery) tenia que cerrar el div que había creado, pero me daba error por que el nodo que buscaba no existía, llegue a este post y me sirvió de guía para validar sin errores si existía o no mi elemento pero no con los script que proponían. llegue a esta solución (en mi caso):

Versión ES2015

```
let divCreadoDinamicamente = document.getElementById('soyUnDivCreado');
let closeModal = divCreadoDinamicamente.querySelector('.close-modal');

    closeModal.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        ( document.body.contains(divCreadoDinamicamente) )
            ? document.body.removeChild(divCreadoDinamicamente)
            : console.log('noooooooo')

    });
```

Versión es5

```
var divCreadoDinamicamente = document.getElementById('soyUnDivCreado');
var closeModal = divCreadoDinamicamente.querySelector('.close-modal');

    closeModal.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if (document.body.contains(divCreadoDinamicamente)) {
           document.body.removeChild(divCreadoDinamicamente);
       }else{
            console.log('noooooooo')
        };
   });
```

Versión Jquery

```
var divCreadoDinamicamente = document.body.querySelector('#soyUnDivCreado');
var closeModal = $('.close-modal');

    closeModal.on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       if($.contains( document.body, divCreadoDinamicamente )) {
            divCreadoDinamicamente.remove();
        }else{
            console.log('noooooooo')
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Un tr creado dinámicamente y agregado a una tabla en cualquier nodo logro saber si existe usando contains(trD) y si deseo eliminarlo sin error lo hago así:

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.setAttribute("id", "x5p");
let trD = document.getElementById("x5p");
if (document.body.contains(trD)) {
    trD.remove();
}
```